# When NSURLConnection delegate is self how to return didReceiveData and didReceiveResponse to my method

Tags: objective-c

I am relatively new to objective-c but struggling with delegates when it comes to NSURLConnection. Below I have an implementation file api.m

Elsewhere in my viewcontrollers I call this api object with the method getGroups and the purpose here is to return the number of groups found when the API request is made. I can see the data in the didReceiveData but how can I get this data back into my getGroups so that I can access it in my viewController?

In my view controller I have something like:

```
NSInteger *numGroups = [apiRequest getGroups];
```

and in my api.m implementation file I have the following. Again everything works I am just not sure how to return the data from didReceiveData back so I can access it in getGroups method.

```
#import "API.h"
#import "Constants.h"
#import "JSONParser.h"

@implementation API

@synthesize user, url, receivedData

-(NSInteger)getGroups {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10];

    [request setValue:APIKEY forHTTPHeaderField:@"apikey"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setURL:url];

    NSURLConnection *myConnection;
    myConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    //How do I access what was append'd in receivedData below

    return 2;

}


/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 NSURLConnection Delegates
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

// Check the response code that was returned
- (NSInteger)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

    return [httpResponse statusCode];

}



// Take a peak at the data returned.
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"DATA: %@", [data description]);

    //How to get this information back up into the getGroups method
    [receivedData appendData: data];

}



// Close the connection
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection {

    NSLog(@"Connection Closed.");

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is in your ViewController that is calling the API set the API's delegate to self. Then you need to add those delegate methods inside your ViewController, not use them out of the API. That way when the `NSURLConnection` tries to call one of the delegate methods it will be accessible within youre ViewController. You also want to make sure you add the delegate protocol inside your ViewController's .h file as well.

As a quick example your VC.h file will contain the following:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
```

Then in your VC.m file you'd have the following methods:

```
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 NSURLConnection Delegates
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

// Check the response code that was returned
- (NSInteger)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

    return [httpResponse statusCode];

}



// Take a peak at the data returned.
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"DATA: %@", [data description]);

    //How to get this information back up into the getGroups method
    [receivedData appendData: data];

}



// Close the connection
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection {

    NSLog(@"Connection Closed.");

}
```

Now when your `NSURLConnection` tries to call didReceiveData it will be called inside your ViewController, not in the API.

As a side note I whole heartedly recommend taking @SK9's advice and make this an Async call to abstract it from the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLConnection`'s `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`, see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest%3areturningResponse%3aerror%3a), will return a data object. Do be sure you're happy to block the current thread like this. I'd prefer for this to be an asynchronous request, with a completion block to handle the return. More details on the page I referred to, but do make reading up on blocks a priority if this is new. The [Short Practical Guid to Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/index.html) might help.